# UINavigationBar title NOT centered horizontally

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, uinavigationcontroller

I have a a storyboard with a Navigation Controller and two View Controllers stacked on top of it as such:
[image]

Somehow (and for reasons I would like to understand) the length of the text in the UINavigationBar of the first UIViewController is affecting the centering of the text in the UINavigationBar of the second View Controller.
Why is this happening and how do fix it?

Here is an example with a shorter text length in the first view controller:

[image]

All I did was change the text from "Privacy Privacy Privacy" to "Privacy" in the UINavigationItem in IB.

Why is this happening and what is the fix? Can this be fixed in IB without code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible through storyboard, you achieve that by setting the back button for the navigation item. Check the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Cool, but what if I don't want a back button?

Comment: you want no back button at all, or a back button without text?

Comment: back button without text please

Comment: add an empty space instead of the word back

Answer (score 2):

Because in `secondViewController` the title of `back` button will be the title of `firstViewController`. Thats why in second view controller the back button title becomes **Privacy Privacy Privacy** thats why it push the main title a little bit right side.

You can stop your `secondViewController` to set `backButton` title to the previous screens title by writing this code in you `secondViewController`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapBackButton))

    }
    @objc func didTapBackButton() {
        //Do what ever you want to do when tap on back button of UINavigationBar here.
    }
```